# Unable to scrape data using xpathSApply

Tags: r, web-scraping

I have read many tutorials and applied several tweaks, but couldn't get it to work for me. I am trying to get all brand names under "Brand" column of a table, from the URL: http://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/

**My Code :**

```
library(XML)
library(RCurl)

html_content <- getURL("http://www.forbes.com/powerful-brands/list/")
html_parsed <- htmlTreeParse(html_content, useInternalNodes = TRUE)

brand_name <- xpathSApply(html_parsed, "//tr[@class='data']/td[3]", xmlValue)
```

I am getting output: `[1] "[NAME]"`
But I want output as follows:

```
Apple 
Google
Microsoft
```

Comment: You're asking others to violate and help you violate Forbes' [ToS](http://www.forbes.com/terms).

Comment: @hrbrmstr I don't know. I think there are protected uses of this data. If he is scraping it to republish it then that's one thing. However if he scrapes it for an academic study I have a *very* hard time believing that's in any way illegitimate. After all, if he transcribed it with a pencil and paper and then used it as input for an essay he writes it would be no different and there's nothing they can put in their ToS that will have the authority to deny him of this right.

Comment: You go right ahead and violate ToS @Hack-R. I'm not stopping you. I've seen lots of folks get C&D letters. Point 1.3 is pretty clear and there are no academic exclusions in the ToS text. Just b/c one _can_ do something doesn't mean one _should_.

Comment: @hrbrmstr You mean "You may use the Content online and solely for your personal, non-commercial use"? That seems like explicit permission. I'm scraping it right now. There's nothing to make me think that's a violation of their ToS, but even if it were it wouldn't matter because transcribing text from a news article isn't illegal unless you do something illegal with it. There's no reason you *shouldn't* do it either. I think you're confused about the context of what's going on. Transcribing information for non-commercial, private use is different than republishing it or profiting off it.

Comment: I'm not going to argue with you @Hack-R. You're determined to do what you want to do with any justification you can find. Go for it.

Comment: I am with @Hack-R. I am trying to scrap just for learning. I won't be using for commercial purpose. I am eagerly waiting for the solution.